# Why can't I use my custom keybinding in ansi-term's char mode?

Tags: ansi-term

I'm an emacs noob

—why can't I use this key

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'other-window)
```

defined in my emacs config, in ansi-term char mode?

Are *all* meta keybindings simply passed raw to the terminal process?

Comment: Read this article: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs .  Key bindings are much more complicated and layered than just `global-set-key`, and this well-written article will explain a lot of things that you didn't know you didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be helpful for you to know that in `char-mode`, all `C-x` key sequences are mapped to `C-c`.  You don't need to define your own key sequence for what you want, therefore, you can just do `C-c C-o`.  As you suspected, this mode passes just about everything along to the terminal that is not prefixed.

Answer (score 4):

From my point of view you should accept Cyberbisson's most **useful** answer. I'll give you a formal one and the way to determine that information for yourself.

> Why can't I use this key
>   `(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'other-window)`
>   defined in my emacs config, in ansi-term char mode?
>
> Are all meta keybindings simply passed raw to the terminal process?

<kbd>F1</kbd> works as help prefix key in `term-mode`. If a window of a buffer in `term-mode` is selected the key sequence <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>M-o</kbd> shows you the command that is bound to <kbd>M-o</kbd> in term char mode and the active map that binds it.

The Help-buffer display the following info:

> M-o runs the command term-send-raw-meta (found in term-raw-map), which
>   is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘term.el’.
>
> It is bound to ESC C-@..N, ESC P..Z, ESC \..DEL.

Almost all Meta keybindings are passed raw in term char mode.
But, there is a gap between <kbd>M-N</kbd> and <kbd>M-P</kbd>. <kbd>M-O</kbd> is not bound by `term-raw-map`. If you do not define it globally it is mapped to <kbd>M-o</kbd>. That lower-letter key is in the range <kbd>M-\</kbd> .. <kbd>M-DEL</kbd> and will therefore be bound to `term-send-raw-meta`.

But, if you bind <kbd>M-O</kbd> explicitly with `(global-set-key (kbd "M-O") 'other-window)` it will also work in term char mode.

If you wanted to stick to <kbd>M-o</kbd> you would need to set the binding of `other-window` directly in `term-raw-map` with the following command:

```el
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-o") 'other-window)
```

Comment: I *presume* that weird-seeming gap is explained by `C-h i g (elisp)Translation Keymaps` and the usage of `<ESC> O` by VT100 terminals.  Note also the final paragraph of that info node.

Comment: @Tobias this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491568/8408220 has given me the idea to use `(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-o") 'nil)` instead. Seems to work—any reason why I shouldn't?

Comment: The standard reason not to mess with `term-raw-map` is that as soon as you run a program in the terminal which makes use of (in this case) `M-o`, you will be unable to use that feature.  If you never run a program in the terminal which recognises that key, then I don't think there would be a problem.  Also, `nil` is self-quoting (just like `t`), so you can remove that quote.  Also, you might want to wrap that inside `(with-eval-after-load "term" ...)` to avoid needing to load term.el first.

Comment: Here help https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77885/16006