# How can I use a key to toggle between line mode and char mode in ansi-term?

Tags: key-bindings, ansi-term

Emacs 27.1

I run `ansi-term` and very often change mode from **line** to **char** mode and visa versa.

[image]

I do this by  mouse click. It's not very convenient. How can I do it with a key binding?

Comment: This is a very low-effort question.  The answer is found very easily in the manual.  You're not a newcomer (you have asked more than 250 emacs questions here), so I think it's ridiculous if you are not checking the manual at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ansi-term` is a terminal-emulator provided by `term` package.

To review default keybindings added by this package, enter <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-keymap` <kbd>RET</kbd> `term-raw-map` (for char mode) or `term-char-map` (for line mode).

Namely, `term-raw-map` outputs (among the other things):

```
C-c C-j         term-line-mode
C-x C-j         term-line-mode
```

`term-mode-map` outputs:

```
C-c C-k         term-char-mode
```

[*Emacs* manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html) also mentioned these keybindings in <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Term Mode`

If the defaults don't suit you, use custom keybindings. For instance:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'term
  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c t l") #'term-line-mode)
  (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c t c") #'term-char-mode))
```

Some may prefer to add a keybinding to `term-raw-escape-map` instead of `term-raw-map` (e.g. see <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `term-set-escape-char`). Omit [prefix key](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html) (<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Prefix Keys`) in such cases, since it is added by the package implicitly.

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'term
  (define-key term-raw-escape-map (kbd "t l") #'term-line-mode))
```

Comment: I try to change keybinging, but  get error: Symbol's value as variable is void: term-raw-map

Comment: `(require 'term)` fixes this. And I'm updating the answer with another option.

Comment: Slightly better to bind to `term-raw-escape-map` (without the escape key prefix), as it makes the binding agnostic to the user's escape key.

Comment: @phils, thanks for the feedback. I added a remark to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs is self–documenting, which means that you can query for what a key or a function does and get accurate information without ever leaving Emacs. Normally you would type `C-h k` to run the `describe-key` function. This would prompt you to type a key sequence, and it would then give you the help for the command that key sequence invokes. Note that in the Emacs GUI, this works for things that you can click on as well!

Of course, in an `ansi-term` buffer the key bindings are a little different. Almost all control keys are sent to your shell directly, so `C-h` is not available (it probably backspaces). You’ll have to run the `describe-key` command directly with `M-x`. Except that `M-x` isn’t available either (for the same reason), you have to use `C-c M-x describe-key`. Then click on the button in the modeline and it will open a window showing you this information:

```
<mode-line> <down-mouse-1> (translated from <down-mouse-1>) at that
spot runs the command term-line-mode, which is an interactive
native-compiled Lisp function in ‘term.el’.

It is bound to C-c C-j and C-x C-j.

(term-line-mode)

Switch to line ("cooked") sub-mode of term mode.
This means that Emacs editing commands work as normally, until
you type M-x term-send-input which sends the current line to the inferior.
```

So there you go, the command you want to run is `term-line-mode`, and it is bound to both `C-c C-j` and `C-x C-j`. If you do the same while the buffer is in line mode, then the button will run `term-char-mode`, which is bound to `C-c C-k`.

Comment: Note that (if available on your keyboard) you can always use `<f1>` as a substitute for `C-h`, which is useful when in term char mode.