# How can I bind a prefix key to escape term-line-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, term, prefix-keys

I've figured out how to get out of char mode, but not the other way around;)

```
#+begin_src elisp
(with-eval-after-load 'term
  ;Terminal Orientation
  ;(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-M-e o l") #'term-line-mode)
  (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-M-e o c") #'term-char-mode)
  )
#+end_src
```

How can I make "C-M-e o l" work?

It complains that C-M-e is not a prefix key, so I guess I have to declare it as a prefix key inside the term-raw-map?

Comment: [How can I use a key to toggle between line mode and char mode in ansi-term?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/77882/28451).

Comment: That article does not use prefix keys, which is the message I get: "is not a prefix key"

Comment: The question is likely a duplicate. Search tag `[prefix-keys]` and delete it if you find a duplicate. Thx.

Comment: `<f1> k C-M-e` tells me "C-M-e runs the command term-send-raw-meta (found in term-raw-map), which is an interactive native-compiled Lisp function in ‘term.el’. It is bound to ESC C-@..N, ESC P..Z and ESC \..DEL."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965966/unset-key-binding-in-emacs/13966287#13966287